# nodejs download multiple files from web

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download multiple files from a OneDrive folder. Below has my code but it will only download the last file and not all of them

```
for(const f in files)
{
    var fileURL = (files[f]["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"]);
    var fileName = (JSON.stringify(files[f].name)).slice(1,-1);

    var request = https.get(fileURL, function(response){
        console.log(fileURL);
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(`./temp/${userId}/${fileName}`);
            response.pipe(file);
        }
        request.setTimeout(60000,function(){
            request.destroy();
        });
    });
}
```

i.e the console log would print

```
FILE_URL1
FILE_URL1
FILE_URL1
```

rather than

```
FILE_URL1
FILE_URL2
FILE_URL3
```

Note that if the `console.log(fileURL)` is placed before `var request https.get...` it prints out the 3 file urls. I'm not sure if its a problem with the loops or if there is something else. I am quite new at javascript so I dont know a lot.

Comment: `const fileURL = `. and `const fileName =`.  vars are functionally scoped, so each callback is going to use the same var,. `const / let` are block scoped so each callback will then have its own instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the **var** with **const** or **let** you will see the different result
Description: [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: Keep going, you are getting better.